# Firefox and Speech Synthesis API

Tags: html, firefox, text-to-speech

I'm creating HTML5 Speech Synthesis application like below link.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk---Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API

Windows7 and Android Chrome33beta or Mac's safari works fine.

but Windows7-Firefox 27 seems support Speech-Synthesis-API,but not work because return empty voice list.

Is there any solution?

Comment: There’s an `about:config` flag called `media.webspeech.synth.enabled` that enables `speechSynthesis` in Firefox. Problem stays, `speechSynthesis.getVoices().length===0`.

Answer (score 4):

Check if Speech Synthesis API is supported your browser
http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-synthesis

You can check it with modernizr
http://v3.modernizr.com/download/#-speechsynthesis

If browser not support it, you can use meSpek.js
http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/

Comment: My Firefox 50 for Linux says I have 0 voices (Fedora 23). Should we need to download by hand each voice? Is there a standard repository for this? Chrome 55 comes already with 19.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like only Firefox OS (and perhaps also, Firefox for Android, I have not checked) bundles and supports a speech synthesis library.

There is an open [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003439) regarding desktop support.

Answer (score 1):

As of release 44, the Speech Synthesis half of the api is available on Firefox Desktop.

But weirdly *still* requires that the flag be set. Under ["Browser Compatibility"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API#Speech_synthesis):

> Can be enabled via the media.webspeech.synth.enabled and media.webspeech.recognition.enable flags in about:config. Note that currently only the speech synthesis part is available in Firefox Desktop — the speech recognition part will be available soon, once the required internal permissions are sorted out.

I wonder why. MDN has even gone to the trouble of whipping up [some nice working examples](https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api/), why not have the functionality enabled be default?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a button to your webpage to read the page out loud, add this code to your website:

```
<script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- //
    var speechpause=0;
    function toggleSpeech(){
      if(speechpause!=1){
        responsiveVoice.pause();
        speechpause=1;
      }else{
        responsiveVoice.resume();
        speechpause=0;
      }
    }
    //-->
</script>
<div style="float:right">
      <input onclick="responsiveVoice.speak($('#some_div_with_content').text(), 'Deutsch Female', {pitch: .7});" type="button" value=" Play" />
      <input onclick="toggleSpeech()" type="button" value="||" />
</div>
```

This uses jquery to get the text of the content, but that could be easily changed.